# Bootstrap Slide in Navbar Clean Up jQuery remove active when user resizes to the min-width

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this script below working well but I can't figure out how to do 1 thing:

**A:** When a user sizes to below the min-width threshold and clicks the toggle to view the menu and then just resizes back to > 767 -- though highly unlikely in real world situations -- the .slide-active class is still there and I can't figure out how to get rid of it. I can fake it with the css (which I've done) but it'd be nice to actually remove it when it's large, tried wrapping the script in an if .navbar-toggle is visible and it only worked on reload, so can't have that.

---

#### DEMO:

**http://jsbin.com/ucARonA/1/edit**

**http://jsbin.com/ucARonA/1**

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //stick in the fixed 100% height behind the navbar but don't wrap it
    $('#slide-nav.navbar .container').
        append($('<div id="navbar-height-col"></div>'));

    // Enter your ids or classes
        var toggler = '.navbar-toggle';
        var pagewrapper = '#page-content';
        var navigationwrapper = '.navbar-header';
        var menuwidth = '100%'; // the menu inside the slide menu itself
        var slidewidth = '80%';
        var menuneg = '-100%';
        var slideneg = '-80%';


    $("#slide-nav").on("click", toggler, function (e) {
      
        var selected = $(this).hasClass('slide-active');

        $('#slidemenu').stop().animate({
          left: selected ? menuneg : '0px'
        });

        $('#navbar-height-col').stop().animate({
          left: selected ? slideneg : '0px'
        });

        $(pagewrapper).stop().animate({
            left: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
        });

        $(navigationwrapper).stop().animate({
            left: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
        });

        $(this).toggleClass('slide-active', !selected);
        $('#slidemenu').toggleClass('slide-active');

        $('#page-content, .navbar, body, .navbar-header').
            toggleClass('slide-active');

    });

});
```

Comment: How are you determining when the user "resizes back to > 767"? Do you have a javascript `onresize` event somewhere or are you just relying on CSS media queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to toggle something on a browser size change and if it meets a min-width, combind a resize event with a if statement.

```
  $(window).on("resize",function(){

  if ($(window).width() > 760) {
   $(selected).removeClass('slide-active');
}

  });
```

Comment: This looks promising. Will try later tonight.

Comment: Thanks for the use of the variable on this. I have added it here and it works well. http://jsbin.com/ifUYAyI/1/edit

Comment: Glad to be able to help. Does this get the bounty?

Comment: Yeah, but they won't let me do it for 10 hour or so.